# WPF DataGrid: Can I cancel a change selection action?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Currently I'm catching the SelectionChanged event, but I would prefer to catch an eariler event that will allow me to cancel the selection change.

Background:

I have two data grids, the lower being a detail of the upper. When the upper changes, I currently prompt the user to save changes. But if there are validation errors, I want to offer them the option to cancel the selection change and fix those errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try binding the upper grid's `ItemsSource` an `ICollectionView` as follows.

```
var items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(*your current bound collection* );
items.CurrentChanging += this.OnCurrentItemChanging;
*your grid*.ItemsSource = items;
```

Then inside OnCurrentItemChanging, you can make `e.Cancel = true` which will cancel the selection change.